# Linux issue on Olimex Lime 2 board after two weeks in operation

Tags: embedded, hang

I'm working on embedded board [Olime Lime 2](https://www.olimex.com/Products/OLinuXino/A20/A20-OLinuXino-LIME2/open-source-hardware). I use official Olimex image.

My system contains only a Nginx web server and a Python program.

I'm testing if my system can operate for long periods. For this, I use 3 same boards with the same image and configuration (as explained above).

After two weeks, one of three board behaved strangely. Firstly, the web server stopped, after few hours, the Python program also stop.

When I detected the problem, I was able to connect in SSH to the board.
But most of commands did not work. For example, `top` command gets stuck (same behavior for others command).
Other strange behavior, I was able to run `ls` in `/root` but gets stuck in `/usr/sbin`.

For the rest, I must specify that my filesystem is run in embedded eMMC. The bootloader of this board try to boot on SD card, if  it not possible it boot on eMMC.
So, I have inserted a SD card with default Olimex image and boot on it to try to found error.
I used `fsck` tools but nothing.. The filesystem seem in perfect state..
After this, I've rebooted on eMMC my board worked like a charm.

I don't understand how it's possible. The only informations that I was able to get are command behavior (gets stuck) and kernel logs ([download here](https://file.io/fhluHixFc7DS)).

To this day, the two others board are working since one month.

Do you have an idea of the origin of the problem ?